# Amazon Pinpoint for Android - AWSMobileClient not found in the SDK jar file

Tags: java, android, aws-sdk

I was trying to implement an easy sample Android app to illustrate how to integrate Amazon Pinpoint - targeted Push Notifications for Mobile Apps. So I was reading and following this documentation below for integration:

[Initializing the Amazon Pinpoint Client - Amazon Pinpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-sdk-android-modify.html)

Then I realized that `AWSMobileClient` is not found inside the SDK jar file. (Other classes such as `PinpointManager` or `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` are available.) If you have imported and read the sample Android project for receiving test Push Notification for Amazon Pinpoint, you may have noticed that this `AWSMobileClient` IS there inside `com.amazonaws.mobile` package.

I'd like to know if I am missing something, this is intended and documented somewhere else, etc.

I have added the following jars:

```
aws-android-sdk-core-2.3.5.jar
aws-android-sdk-pinpoint-2.3.5.jar
```

and the cognito dependency:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.5'
```

(`AWSMobileClient` is required for registering and handling tokens, refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-sdk-android-modify.html#d0e4313) for more info.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the sentence in the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-sdk-android-modify.html#d0e4313):

> In the following example, the AWSMobileClient class is provided in the AWS Mobile Hub sample code to reference the Amazon Pinpoint object.

So it seems like `AWSMobileClient` is not a part of the SDK but defined for sample project.

[UPDATED]
If you finish adding your app on Mobile Hub and get ready to integrate SDK, you will see `Android Setup Steps` section and there it also says,

> Copy the Mobile Hub Helper and Custom Code
>   Copy the contents of the java/com/amazonaws folder from the helper code you downloaded into the java/com folder of your Android Studio project.
>
> This folder contains a set of helper classes that have been custom generated for you. These were generated based on your project configuration and on the AWS cloud resources and identifiers that were created for you when you configured the project. These classes simplify the use of all the SDKs that are required to support your project.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can add this dependency in the app's build.gradle

`compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that

```
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.+@aar') { transitive = true }
```

worked when the following two options didn't:

```
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }
```

and

```
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }
```